# mat-spinner does not stop spinning

Tags: angular, typescript, eventemitter

I have a component (dialog-component) where I refer to another component (DATA-component).
When I set

```
isLoaded = false
```

(in dialog-component-ts) and I use

```
this.isLoaded.emit(true);
```

(in DATA-component), then
isLoaded is being set true (in dialog-component-ts),
but the mat-spinner does not stop spinning and the loaded data is not being shown.
I already use pretty much the same code in other components where it works.
When I set

```
isLoaded = true
```

(in dialog-component-ts) then there is no spinner and the data is being displayed.
Any ideas what the issue could be?

dialog-component-html:

```
 <mat-card>
    <div *ngIf="!isLoaded" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" class="loading">
      <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
    </div>
    <app-data *ngIf="selectedDialogData === enum1" [fxShow]="isLoaded"
                       (title)="onComponentTitleChange($event)"
                       (isLoaded)="onComponentReadyStateChange($event)"
                       (dialogDataChanged)="onSelectedDialogDataChange($event)">
    </app-data>
 </mat-card>
```

dialog-component-ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})


export class DialogComponent {

  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public dialogData: SomeModel) { }

  public isLoaded = false;
  
...

  public onComponentReadyStateChange(state) {
    this.isLoaded = state;
  }
...
```

data-compontent-ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-data',
  templateUrl: './data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class WorkingtypeDataComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() title = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @Output() isLoaded = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @Output() dialogDataChanged = new EventEmitter<EnumList>();

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public dialogData: SomeModel,
              private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>,
              private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private Service: SomeService,
              private dialog: MatDialog) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isLoaded.emit(false);
    this.currentElement = this.dialogData.changeElement;
    this.alreadyExistingElementNames = this.dialogData.alreadyExistingElementNames;
    this.isEditing = this.currentElement.name != null;
    const title = `texts.${this.isEditing ? 'edit' : 'add'}`;
    this.title.emit(title);
    this.isLoaded.emit(true);
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint inside `onComponentReadyStateChange` and see if it gets called with the right values?

Comment: yes, it does. in the end is being set true. but the mat-spinner does not stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `ChangeDetection.OnPush` Angular only runs change detection when @Input changes are detected.

To act on child Outputs you need to manually trigger a change detection cycle.

For example using `this.cdr.detectChanges()`

[Guide](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4)

Comment: This lead to another error that a FormGroup instance was being expected. So I added    *ngIf="loginForm" in my html and now it's working.